# Wordpress Custom fields display file URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code and need to show THREE things from my custom post type called fact-sheet.

1. The Title
2. The summary (fact_sheet_summary)
3. A file upload URL (fact_sheet_pdf_link)

I can get the first two to work but no idea how to do the third.
Basically my output should be...

`The Title
 The Summary paragraph
 Click here to download as PDF`

Any ideas how I can query to list all of these post type results? Is there a better way to do this rather than what I have below? The main problem is, I can't get the URL of the uploaded file.

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_type' => 'fact-sheet',
'order' => 'ASC',
));

if($posts)
{


foreach($posts as $post)
{
    echo '<span class="fact-sheet-title">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</span><br />';
    echo '<p><span class="fact-sheet-summary">' . the_field('fact_sheet_summary') . '</span></p>';
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's better to use `query_posts()` as you can use [The Loop default structure](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

As for the custom fields (Using [ACF Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)), you're using `the_field()`, which automatically *echoes* the retrieved field value. You can use, in other hand, the `get_field()` function, which just returns the value of the field.

You could do something like this:

```
// Query all posts from 'fact-sheet' post_type
query_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'fact-sheet',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    // Getting all posts, limitless
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));

// Loop throught them
while(have_posts()){
    the_post();

    echo '<span class="fact-sheet-title">' . get_the_title() . '</span><br />';
    echo '<p><span class="fact-sheet-summary">' . get_field('fact_sheet_summary') . '</span></p>';
    // Echos the link to PDF Download
    echo '<p><a href="'. get_field('fact_sheet_pdf_link') .'" target="_blank">Click here to download as PDF</a></p>';

}

// Once you're done, you reset the Default WP Query
wp_reset_query();
```

In case you might need further explanation about `wp_reset_query()`, [check this out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query).

Comment: this works but for two things...
1. Link returns as http://sitename.com/Array instead of http://sitename.com/filename.pdf
2. How can we get it to loop through ALL posts and not just those set by wordpress settings (which I have set to 5)...

Comment: @lowercase I edited and added `'posts_per_page' => -1` which will fetch all posts, limitless. About your first question, it's about how you created the custom field in ACF panel. Edit the field you created and ask it to [return the file URL](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/file/).

Comment: Correct! thanks so much. I switched custom field to return URL and posts_per_page worked great.
Much Appreciated!

Comment: @lowercase anytime :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? It's slightly modified from the manual of the WP Codex (not much)

```
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'post_mime_type' => array('application/pdf'),
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, true );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

If it works, maybe it's better to modify a working sample to your needs - by adding your custom fields. Just my thoughts :-)